# Is it possible to render a panorama in perspectives other than full 360°x180°?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

#### Update

This is now possibly natively as of 2.74. See my [answer below](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23221/599).

---

Is it possible to render a panorama in cycles that is **not** a full 360x180 view?

E.g. `360° x 30°`?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The panoramic camera has three types - the two fisheye types have field of view / fov and lens

Comment: @sambler I only see FOV on *Fisheye Equidistant*. Anyway, I was hoping for something that looked more like a stitched panorama (not a fisheye lens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a very efficient way of doing this because it requires rendering the entire $360^\circ \times 180^\circ$ image and then cropping off a good chunk of it, but it seems to be the only option.

Here is a diagram:

[image]

$H$ is the height of the $360^\circ \times 180^\circ$ image, $h$ is the height of the cropped ($360°\times n^\circ$) image, and $n$ is the desired angle.  When $n$ is $180^\circ$ we can see that $D$ would be $\frac{1}{2}$ the height of the image so $D=\frac{H}{2}$.  From here it is just a little simple trigonometry and we can get:

$$
h = \sin(\frac{n}{2})\frac{H}{2}2 = \sin(\frac{n}{2})H
$$

Using your example of $30^\circ$ we get $h = \sin(15) H ≈ 0.26 H$  A slight rearrangement gives $H ≈ \frac{h}{0.26}$ which you can use to plug in the desired height and get the height you must use to render.

Comment: Some using some python to set the render border should fix the efficiency problem. (will accept after I test it)

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB4118c1b4e6ae04988c310d785bd1802c46187e3a) (will be in 2.74).

> Cycles: Adding field-of-view options to the equirectangular panorama camera
>
> This patch adds the option to set minimum/maximum latitude/longitude values for
> the equirectangular panorama camera in Cycles, as discussed in [`T34400`](https://developer.blender.org/T34400).

Answer (score 1):

360°x180° puts out a 2d image that's distorted so that the angles are now x and y axis correct?

Just render the 360°x180° and cut the x120° (two thirds of the 180°) that you don't want off?

Comment: Could you add how to determine how many pixels to cut off? (convert degrees to pixels?)

Comment: @gandalf3 to simply crop the 360x180 image to be the same size as a 360x(n) image you can use the formula h'=h*sin(n/2).  Where h' is the height of the new image and h is the height of the 360x180 image.

Comment: @PGmath Throw that in an answer and I'll accept it ;)