# How to convert an HDR Image created / rendered on Blender to a format acceptable on social media and websites?

Tags: hdri

I rendered a HDRi on Blender from my ambient - to look like real state presentation - and I want to convert this HDRi file into a format acceptable on Facebook and / or other media as they doesn't open HDRi's.
I don't even know what is the format of 360 (equirectangular, spherical actually) photos generated from cameras and phones, otherwise I could do my research on it :(
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Surely this is better asked on Facebook or other social media sites.

Comment: You can save your HDRI as .png and/or .jpg if you want to. They should work fine on facebook. No need for .exr or anything fancy like that.

Comment: Hey :). So you want to render a 360° photo/video and upload it to FB?

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry for the links only answer, but this is too long for comments.*

---

You are mixing two different concepts:

### **1. HDRi**

stands for High Dynamic Range image, that has larger colour values than those that can be displayed by any screen. They are used mostly as environment textures to light scenes.

### **2. 360 images**

concept of environment projection https://wiki.panotools.org/Projections

Watch https://www.coursera.org/lecture/360-vr-video-production/equirectangular-projection-cubemaps-uTv8r

Most HDRi is mapped used in 3D and VR is using equirectangular projection, but is not mandatory.

As to how to do this in blender, it has been asked before:

[Blender panoramic render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160590/blender-panoramic-render)

[Is it possible to render a panorama in perspectives other than full 360°x180°?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5524/is-it-possible-to-render-a-panorama-in-perspectives-other-than-full-360x180)

[equirectangular rendering for Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/equirectangular-rendering-for-blender-internal)

[how do I bake an animated sky box using cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13431/how-do-i-bake-an-animated-sky-box-using-cycles)